# CRON to run on only one Docker Container

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, cron, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have my application which is Dockerized and running on AWS instances.

In my DockerFile, I have the below statement to run CRON

```
RUN bundle exec whenever --update-crontab
```

AWS console is configured in auto-scalable mode and based on the desired number of instances configured, I have 3 containers running for my application.
I have issue with my CRON running in all the containers.

```
docker exec -it <container-id> service cron status

* cron is running
```

Appears for all the 3 containers.

**How can I configure CRON to run on only one Container.**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `RUN bundle exec whenever --update-crontab` in your Dockerfile it will run on every image that is built with the Dockerfile.

You have a few options:

Create a separate service `cron-service`

This service could run the cron (use the Dockerfile you have now for the `cron-service`) and create a new Dockerfile (remove the cron RUN command) so everything works as expected and cron only runs once...

Comment: Will update answer with additional options in a few